# Issues calling on a Stata file and library

Tags: r

I am having an issue trying to call on a data file in Rstudio.

I installed the `foreign` package and activated it in the packages tab.

highlighted `library(foreign)`;  Run

highlighted `fertil=read.dta("C:/Users/steve/Downloads/FERTIL1.dta")` Run

That's where the file is stored

In Console:

```
library("foreign", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.4")
fertil=read.dta("C:/Users/steve/Downloads/FERTIL1.dta")
```

> Warning message:
>   In read.dta("C:/Users/steve/Downloads/FERTIL1.dta") :
>   cannot read factor labels from Stata 5 files

Comment: Are these very old files? Stata seems to be on version 15 and this error message sounds like it thinks the data is in a Stata version 5 format. Maybe try to import the data into Stata and export it in a more friendly format for R. Hard to say without knowing what's in there.